# get previous objects before x object

Tags: django

how can I get say the previous 5 objects before x object when I know x's id?

For example I get the 5 last objects of a model like this

```
numPosts = Post.objects.filter(topic=topic).count()
pre = numPosts - 5
posts = Post.objects.filter(topic=topic).order_by('date')[pre:numPosts]
```

Now if I know the id of the post with the oldest date, how can I get the 5 next objects, or less if there are not enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(topic=topic).order_by('date')

x = posts.get(id=id)
next_five = posts.filter(date__lt=x.date)[:5]

should return the next 5 (or less) objects
```